# How To Start New Activity with Intent Using SherlockListFragment?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a listfragment with sherlock list fragment like this :

```
public class FragmentTab1 extends SherlockListFragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab1, null);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, DaerahWisata.pantai));
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent a;
    switch (position) {

    case 0:
        a = new Intent(FragmentTab1.this, Maps.class); //error
        break;
        if (null != a)
            startActivity(a);
    }
}
```

But in new Intent i get error like this :  The constructor intent is undefined. Whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
  a = new Intent(getActivity(), Maps.class);
```

instead of

```
  a = new Intent(FragmentTab1.this, Maps.class);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it before, but there was a mistake, but now it is working.